# Transfer Learning - Val_loss strange behaviour

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, image-recognition, transfer-learning

I am trying to use transfer-learning on MobileNetV2 from keras.application in phyton.
My images belongs to 4 classes with an amount of 8000, 7000, 8000 and 8000 images in the first, second, third and last class. My images are gray-scaled and resized from 1024x1024 to 128x128.

I removed the classification dense layers from MobileNetV2 and added my own dense layers:

```
global_average_pooling2d_1 (Glo Shape = (None, 1280)         0 Parameters                            
______________________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)                 Shape=(None, 4)            5124 Parameters      
______________________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)             Shape=(None, 4)            0  Parameters                        
________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)                 Shape=(None, 4)            20 Parameters                         
__________________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)                 Shape=(None, 4)            20 Parameters                        

Total params: 2,263,148

Trainable params: 5,164

Non-trainable params: 2,257,984
```

As you can see I added 2 dense layers with dropout as regularizer.
Furhtermore, I used the following

```
opt = optimizers.SGD(lr=0.001, decay=4e-5, momentum=0.9)

model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

batch_size = 32
```

My results on training are very weird... :

Epoch

1    loss: 1.3378 - acc: 0.3028 - val_loss: 1.4629 - val_acc: 0.2702

2    loss: 1.2807 - acc: 0.3351 - val_loss: 1.3297 - val_acc: 0.3208

3    loss: 1.2641 - acc: 0.3486 - val_loss: 1.4428 - val_acc: 0.3707

4    loss: 1.2178 - acc: 0.3916 - val_loss: 1.4231 - val_acc: 0.3758

5    loss: 1.2100 - acc: 0.3909 - val_loss: 1.4009 - val_acc: 0.3625

6    loss: 1.1979 - acc: 0.3976 - val_loss: 1.5025 - val_acc: 0.3116

7    loss: 1.1943 - acc: 0.3988 - val_loss: 1.4510 - val_acc: 0.2872

8    loss: 1.1926 - acc: 0.3965 - val_loss: 1.5162 - val_acc: 0.3072

9    loss: 1.1888 - acc: 0.4004 - val_loss: 1.5659 - val_acc: 0.3304

10   loss: 1.1906 - acc: 0.3969 - val_loss: 1.5655 - val_acc: 0.3260

11   loss: 1.1864 - acc: 0.3999 - val_loss: 1.6286 - val_acc: 0.2967

(...)

Summarizing, the loss of training does not decrease anymore and is still very high. The model also overfits.
You may ask why I added only 2 dense layers with 4 neurons in each. In the beginning I tried different configurations (e.g. 128 neurons and 64 neurons and also different regulaziers), then overfitting was a huge problem, i.e. accuracy on training was almost 1 and loss on test was still far away from 0.

I am a little bit confused what is going on, since something tremendously is wrong here.

Fine-tuning attempts:
Different numbers of neurons in the dense layers in the classification part varying from 1024 to 4.
Different learning rates (0.01, 0.001, 0.0001)
Different batch sizes (16,32, 64)
Different regulaziers L1 with 0.001, 0.0001

Results:
Always huge overfitting

```
base_model = MobileNetV2(input_shape=(128, 128, 3), weights='imagenet', include_top=False)

# define classificator
x = base_model.output
x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
x = Dense(4, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dropout(0.8)(x)
x = Dense(4, activation='relu')(x)
preds = Dense(4, activation='softmax')(x) #final layer with softmax activation

model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=preds)

for layer in model.layers[:-4]:
    layer.trainable = False

opt = optimizers.SGD(lr=0.001, decay=4e-5, momentum=0.9)
model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

batch_size = 32
EPOCHS = int(trainY.size/batch_size)

H = model.fit(trainX, trainY, validation_data=(testX, testY), epochs=EPOCHS, batch_size=batch_size)
```

Result should be that there is no overfitting and val_loss close to 0. I know that from some paper working on similiar image sets.

UPDATE:
Here are some pictures of val_loss, train_loss and accuracy:
[2 dense layers with 16 and 8 neurons, lr =0.001 with decay 1e-6, batchsize=25](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c3zpt.png)

Comment: Results from the image you linked doesn't look too bad to me. Looks like when a general model is trained and reached capacity. But I assume the overfitting only starts occurring once you increase the number of neurons past 16/8? The image size reduction you are doing could be very significant. Sure you're not using too much detail?

Comment: Since you're using GlobalAveragePooling, is it necessary for that big a size reduction?

Answer (score 0):

Here, you used
`x = Dropout(0.8)(x)`
which means to drop 80% but i assume you need 20%
so replace it by `x = Dropout(0.2)(x)`

Also, please go thorugh [keras documentation](https://keras.io/layers/core/) for the same if needed.

an extract from the above documentation

> keras.layers.Dropout(rate, noise_shape=None, seed=None)
>
> **rate**: float between 0 and 1. Fraction of the input units to drop.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what the error was from above, but i know how to fix it. I completely trained the pretrained network (aswell one dense layer with 4 neurons and softmax). The results are more than satisfying.
I also tested on VGG16, where I trained only the dense output layer and it totally worked fine.

It seems to be that MobileNetV2 learns features which undesirable for my set of datas. My data sets are radar images, which looks very artificially (choi williams distribution of 'LPI'-signals). On the other hand those images are very easy (they are basicially just edges in a grayscale image), so it is still unkown to me why model-based transfer learning doesnt work for MobileNetV2).

Answer (score 0):

Could be the result of your dropout rate being to high. You do not show your data generators so I can't tell if there is an issue there but I suspect that you need to compile using

```
loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy'
```